# Using two different maps on one atlas page

Tags: qgis, print-composer, mapping, atlas

I can generate an atlas for 26 different map extents (numbered 1-26) and put them on 26 different pages. I want to put two different maps from the series on the one page i.e. map extents 1 + 2 on page 1, map extents 3 + 4 on page 2 ...  map extents 25 + 26 on page 13.

Is there any way of doing this? (I though by having two different atlas's bit can't seem to do this in one print layout).

Answer (score 9):

Yes you can do this with the expression string builder overriding the extent of the second map regarding the extent of the first map which is controlled by the atlas. Supposing your two maps have the same extend and the atlasfeature is a point feature. Works similar for polygon features with the centroid.

[image]

with the following expressions for the extents of map2 you can control Xmin:

```
with_variable( 'w',
   bounds_width( map_get(item_variables('map1'),'map_extent')),
   x(geometry(get_feature_by_id( @atlas_layername,  @atlas_featureid + 1  )))-@w/2)
```

The expression takes the with of map1 and uses the position of the next atlasfeature to calculate the extent of the following map. for the Ymin the expression is:

```
with_variable( 'h',
   bounds_width( map_get(item_variables('map1'),'map_extent')),
   y(geometry(get_feature_by_id( @atlas_layername,  @atlas_featureid + 1  )))-@h/2)
```

Comment: Very nice: Great answer! Remains to add that for `X max` and `Y max` the expression remains the same, just with `+@w/2` (instead of `-@w/2`) at the end.

Comment: I tried this and it works fine on the first page, I can see Map Extent 1 and 2 on the first page. When I click 'Next Feature' in the Atlas I expect to see Map Extent 3 (on left) and 4 (on right). However, when I click 'Next Feature' in the Atlas it shows Map Extent 2 (again) on left and Map Extent 3 on right. Any ideas what I am missing?